# Difficulty comprehending the behavior of a function which has returned an empty list unto itself

Tags: python, list, attributes, iterator, typeerror

I am working with some codes that make use of a property that is best exemplified with the examples below that I am demonstrating with my interpreter. I have difficulty understanding why the codes work the way they do.

```
In [377]: def a():
   .....:     return []
   .....:
```

First I have defined a simple function that returns an empty list unto itself.

```
In [381]: a()
Out[381]: []
```

Next, I iterate over this function to try an print out something:

```
In [397]: for i in a():
   .....:     print a.hello
   .....:     print a.hello()
   .....:     

In [398]:
```

I did not get any output. I noticed that I get the exact same thing when doing the `for` loop when I did a return of a `tuple` instead of `list`:

```
In [399]: def a():
   .....:     return ()
   .....:
```

It seems to me that it has something to do with the `list` and `tuples` being empty. However, what really puzzled was why I did not get any sort of error when I called the `hello` attribute on `a` as part of the `for` loop. Shouldn't I be getting like a `TypeError` telling me that object `a` has no attribute `hello` and `hello()` or at least something along those lines? What's going on here?

I appreciate any explanations, and please correct my misconceptions if I'm mistaken.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for whatever in a():
  do_stuff_with_whatever(whatever)
```

only executes `do_stuff_with_whatever` if `a()` returns an iterable that has elements in it.  Otherwise, what would be the value of `whatever` on the first pass?

In other words, the statements `a.hello` and `a.hello()` never have a chance to get executed because there is nothing to iterate over.  If you change your function to:

```
def a():
    return [1]
```

Then you'll start seeing an `AttributeError` because `a` has no `hello` attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much! This clarifies everything about this.